# Angular ng-repeat: Keep focus to input when order changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to show an ordered list.
I have an input in the list which where you can specify the order.
When you change it, sometimes it stays in focus (when the input goes down) but when the input gets sorted up, I loose focus on the input. How can I solve this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Xfe/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='person in Persons | orderBy: "number" track by person.id'>
        <p>{{ person.name }} <input type='number' ng-model='person.number'></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is due to how the DOM elements get recreated when the order changes.  I created a directive that will maintain the focus.  I'm not sure if this is the best way or not, but it works.

```
app.directive('setFocus', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            personId: '@',
            index: '@',
            selectedPersonId: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch("index", function(currentValue, previousValue) {
                if($scope.personId == $scope.selectedPersonId)
                {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        $element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

You pass it in th personId of the element, the index of the element, and the selectedPersonId (whichever one has the focus).  It watches for an index change to occur, and then checks if the element's personId is equal to the selectedPersonId (setting the focus if it is).

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input class='filter' type='number' ng-model='person.number' ng-focus="selectPerson(person.id)" set-focus person-id="{{person.id}}" selected-person-id="{{selectedPersonId}}" index="{{$index}}">
```

Seems like kind of a lot of extra stuff to do something that seems simple.  Maybe someone else has a more clever way.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/Q3Xfe/2/).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, even though I hope there is a better solution where Angular does something similar using the track by statement or so... i don't actually know... but sounds like it should be possible to do easier especially because it is able to stay in focus when going down. But this solution helps me a lot! I only have one question: What is the $timeout for? why not focus straight away?

Comment: I think that when you increase the person.number, it leaves your selected textbox alone (that's why it retains focus), removes the appropriate textboxes from the DOM and reinserts them before the selected box.  When you decrese the person.number, it removes your selected textbox from the DOM (which is why it loses focus) and reinserts it before the other textboxes.  If you don't wrap the `$element[0].focus` in a `$timeout`, you get an error about the $digest cycle already being in progress.  The `$timeout` makes it wait until the $digest cycle is over, and then triggers another one.

Answer (score 8):

A more generic approach:

```
app.directive("keepFocus", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    /*
    Intended use:
        <input keep-focus ng-model='someModel.value'></input>
    */
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $element[0].focus();
                });
                return value;
            });

        }
    };
}])
```

Then just:

```
<input keep-focus ng-model="person.number"/>
```